# Excel VBA issue copying from filtered data set

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a large project, but am fairly new to VBA. Part of what I am trying to do requires me to copy data from a pre-filtered data set over to a new sheet. From what I have found online it seems like the best way to do this is by using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me.

Currently when the code runs it copies all cell values to the new sheet, even filtered or blank cells. My goal is to just have the visible cells copy over.

Here is the relevant code that I have so far...

```
Sheets(dataSheetName).Range(yColumn & periodStart & ":" & yColumn & periodEnd).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(ySourceColumn & VBAheaderRow + groupCount(groupIndex) + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Edit: People have asked for additional context and information. The goal of this code is to add trendlines to charts based on multiple series. From what I could find the only way to do this was to combine the data into one sheet and then can use slope and intercept formulas to solve for the trendline. This seems to be working when the data sources are unfiltered, but I want the user to be able to filter data have the correct trendlines. Hopefully that makes sense.

Here is a small section of the data I am working with. There are hundred of columns and thousands of rows, but the data is being pulled from here:

[image: Data source to be copied]

The data set is further broken down into time periods and each time period is in a different "Group." The user could filter this in essentially infinite ways and I would like to then copy the filtered data to a new sheet where it is added to the appropriate group column. The header of the source sheet looks like this.

[image: Paste loaction]

This would ultimately be hidden from the user, but data would be copied to the yellow cells and then the slope, intercept, and series values are "saved" (copied to a summary table) and used to plot the trendlines. My previous code is in a loop which runs through each time period and copies the data (y source column and x source column) to the correct column in the "Paste location" image. This is also repeated for each graph that is created.

And here is a larger section of code. Again this is part of a huge sub and I don't want to post the entire thing (unless someone really wants it), but here is a larger section of the code:

```
For periodIndex = 1 To 10
    If graphPeriod = "Yes" Then
        If XYShowTrendlines = "Yes" Then
            'copies the values into the VBA worksheet to graph trendlines as series
            Sheets(dataSheetName).Range(yColumn & periodStart & ":" & yColumn & periodEnd).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(Split(Cells(1, (groupIndex * 2)).Address, "$")(1) & VBAHeaderRowXYGroupData + groupCount(groupIndex) + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets(dataSheetName).Range(xColumn & periodStart & ":" & xColumn & periodEnd).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(Split(Cells(1, (groupIndex * 2) - 1).Address, "$")(1) & VBAHeaderRowXYGroupData + groupCount(groupIndex) + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Worksheets(VBASheetName).Calculate
            'copies the calculated x and y values to the summary table
            Dim index As Integer
            For index = 1 To 12
                If IsError(Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(Split(Cells(1, ((index + (index Mod 3)) / 3) + 4).Address, "$")(1) & "3")) = False Then
                    If index Mod 3 = 0 Then
                        'slope and r-squared
                        Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(Split(Cells(1, (index / 3) + 4).Address, "$")(1) & "3:" & Split(Cells(1, (index / 3) + 4).Address, "$")(1) & "4").Copy
                    Else
                        'values
                        Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(Split(Cells(1, index - ((index - (index Mod 3)) / 3)).Address, "$")(1) & "10:" & Split(Cells(1, index - ((index - (index Mod 3)) / 3)).Address, "$")(1) & "11").Copy
                    End If
                    Sheets(VBASheetName).Range(Split(Cells(1, index * 2 + 9).Address, "$")(1) & VBAHeaderRowXYGroupData + graphIndex & ":" & Split(Cells(1, index * 2 + 10).Address, "$")(1) & VBAHeaderRowXYGroupData + graphIndex).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
                End If
            Next index
            Worksheets(XYSheetName).Activate
        End If
    End If
Next periodIndex
```

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: And which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Can you also show a sample of your sheet?

Comment: Yes, first time posting so wasn't sure what all to include. I'm using Office 365 so Excel 2016. This is part of 250+ line sub that works with the data set and relevant graphs (admittedly I should probably break this up). Should I attempt to pull out all lines relevant to this problem and post those?

Comment: Please give m,ore feedback on the code you are using.

Comment: You could use Sheets(dataSheetName).AutoFilter.Range.Copy or .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy to not copy the header row.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how auto filter would help in this situation? I don't want to actually filter any data. I just want to copy the visible data based on what the user chooses to filter out.